# Conjecture for the number of ordinary lines

Tags: matroid-theory

Let S(n) be the minimum number of ordinary lines determined over every set of n non-collinear points.

S(11)=6  S(14)=7

A=(3/7)*n

{B} = {B|3 ≤ B < n, B ∈ Odd prime}, {D} = {D|4 ≤ D <n, D ∈ Square number}

Let bₘ be the total number of elements of the finite Set {B}
Let dₘ be the total number of elements of the finite Set {D}

Conjecture1: A ≤ S(n) ≤ n−bₘ        {n|3 ≤ n ≤ +∞, n ∈ positive integer}?

Conjecture2: A ≤ S(n) ≤ n−bₘ−dₘ {n|6 ≤ n ≤ +∞, n ∈ even numbers}?

For example: if n = 11, there are three odd numbers (3, 5, 7) in {B}, then bₘ=3,
(3/7) ∗11 ≤ S(11) ≤ 11−3

If n = 14, there are five odd numbers (3, 5, 7, 11, 13) in {B}, then bₘ=5; for 14>6,
there are two square numbers (4, 9) in {D}, so dₘ=2,
(3/7) ∗ 14 ≤ S(14) ≤ 14−5−2

Link 1: https://en.jinzhao.wiki/wiki/Sylvester%E2%80%93Gallai_theorem

Link 2: https://oeis.org/A003034

Please point out my mistakes and express your opinions!

Thank you very much!

Comment: Your link 1 does not resolve for me.  What is the question?  MO is generally not a place for stating conjectures without specific questions.

Comment: Hi LSpice, I wanted to see if S(n)have upper limits '(n-b＿m)'and 'n-b_m-d_m'. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Have you seen Ben Green & Terence Tao, On Sets Defining Few Ordinary Lines,
Discrete & Computational Geometry volume 50, pages409–468 (2013) ?

Comment: They proved the number of ordinary lines is at least n/2. Furthermore, if n is odd number, the number of ordinary lines  are at least 3n/4 - C, for some constant C